# Disambiguating identical columns in a join

Tags: mysql

[Yes, I've searched for an answer for this here and in google but this is a little difficult to query for.]

(MySQL database.)

```
messages table:
messageid
senderid
recipientid

people table:
personid
name
```

I wish to issue a query that returns the following:

```
messageid     sender_name   recipient_name
1             larry             jane
2             mark              alice
```

etc.

The following doesn't do it, and I expected that it would not, but it's a place to start:

```
select m.messageid, p.name as "sender_name", p.name as "recipient_name"
from messages m, people p
where m.senderid = p.personid and m.recipientid = p.personid
```

The issue is that I don't know how in sql to specifically reference the sender and the recipient since they are part of the same join clause, if that makes sense.

thanks

Comment: Just a FYI incase there is confusion...Your query here is using older syntax (functional, but harder to read). "from messages m ,people p where m.senderID = p.personID" is the quivlent of : "from messages m inner join people p on m.senderID = p.personID". The answers below use this newer syntax (by newer I mean from '92), but they are equivlent to what you are using here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query return only messages that is sent from a person to itself. Something like:

```
select m.messageid, p1.name as sender_name, p2.name as recipient_name 
from messages m, 
join people p1
     on m.senderid = p1.personid 
join people p2
     on m.recipientid = p2.personid
```

That is you need one join for sender and one join for receiver

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
select m.messageid, pSender.name as "sender_name", pRecipient.name as "recipient_name"
from messages m
inner join people pSender on m.senderId = pSender.personId
inner join people pRecipient on m.recipientid = pRecipient.personId
```

For your join method (i think this should work... i'm not very familiar with comma joins)

```
select m.messageid, p.name as "sender_name", p.name as "recipient_name"
from messages m, people pSender, people pRecipient
where m.senderid = pSender.personid and m.recipientid = pRecipient.personid
```

Comment: You're not going to find an exact answer to your questions all the time, I would really brush up on how joins work.  Not sure what DBMS you're working with, but personally I am not a fan of implied join method you're using - i have no idea what it's called but I *think* it might be getting depricated for some DBMSes?

Comment: the database is MySQL

Answer (score 2):

You can join the same table into the query twice, just alias it differently, something aking to:

```
select m.messageid, s.name as "sender_name", r.name as "recipient_name"
from messages m
    inner join people s on m.senderid = s.personid 
    inner join people r on m.recipientid = r.personid
```

Comment: you're selecting "r.name" twice where the sender_name should be s.name. I did an edit but it was rejected by three people for some reason.  Yay.

Comment: fixed. Thanks for the heads up.